# Checking if Linked List joins back to start

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to check if the last node of a linked list points to the head. This code seems to give a positive result for the problem, but also gives a false positive for a list that contains a node pointing to a non-head node.

I've been trying different things such as checking if the slow node is equal to the head at the return true point, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
public boolean isLinkedToStart(Node head) {
    if (head == null) {
        return false;
    }
    Node fast = head.next;
    Node slow = head;
    while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
        if (fast.next.next == slow) {
            return true;
        }
        fast = fast.next.next;
        slow = slow.next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This algorithm (commonly known as the [Tortoise and Hare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) algorithm, is a general cycle detection algorithm. It returns true if the linked list contains **any** cycle, not necessarily one that points back to the head. What you want is a more specific variant.

Comment: is the head defined in any special/identifiable way?

Comment: Good question by the way! This turned out more challenging than we all thought!

Comment: Do you really need a slow and fast node ? Why not just traverse once through the list and check if there is a node pointing to head or a node pointing to null ? Note that the slow-fast algorithm is to bring down complexity from O(n^2) to O(n). This problem can already be solved in O(n) since the head is known.

Comment: @user1952500 read my comment on HC_'s answer to know what the problem with that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public boolean isLinkedToStart(Node head) {
    if (head == null) {
        return false;
    }
    Node fast = head.next;
    Node slow = head;
    while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
        fast = fast.next.next;
        slow = slow.next;
        if(slow.next == head)
            return true;
        if (fast == slow)
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Okay, third time is a charm.

If a cycle is found before slow makes it way to head, then we found a different cycle. If slow makes it to head, then the cycle is to head.

Comment: You're the first one to mention "Floyd Cycle Finding Algorithm".

Comment: Oh, my bad.. I think I misunderstood the question. Removing other comments.

Comment: I guess this will infinite loop in the case he gets a false positive

Comment: Yeah, I think it should be just a Tortoise-Hare with an added conditional gate at the end.

Comment: I've tried this, but it returns false for some correct circular lists. I've also tried `slow.next == head` just in case

Comment: @sf2 I see why it doesn't work now. This problem may be more difficult than it seems. You may have no other choice but to save in another list every element you've passed, and on each iteration checking all of them

Comment: @sf2 Edited again, this one i'm sure of now!

Comment: Maybe you should consider returning three results (nocycle, subcycle, fullcycle), rather than just a boolean true/false?  Or two methods, one which checks for any (sub)cycle, and a second that checks for the specific (full)cycle?

Comment: @ChuckCottrill Easily editable if the requirements change. Just change the first return false; to return whatever other value you want. Maybe -1, 0, 1?. In this `specific` question though, the OP wants false.

Comment: @Cruncher Given that a shot, but it's now giving false results for correct lists. I've also tried your suggestion of keeping tabs on how many times the head has been seen, but this seems to return the same for any list I give it (circular or cyclic)

Comment: @sf2 Can you give an example list that this gives false for?

Comment: Oh, I see, slow appears to meet fast at the end of the list, not back at the front. Changing it to `slow.next==head` should work

Comment: That edit works for even numbers of nodes in a linked list, but not for odd for some reason

Comment: @Cruncher certainly, just trying to help the OP understand the problem and solution a little better.

Comment: @sf2 Changed the order in which things happen. Because we were comparing `fast.next.next` to `slow`, with an odd number of elements, fast was able to loop around too quickly to "catch up" to slow before it got to loop back to head. Now we do all of the pointer changes first, then check for the loop to head, and after all that we check for an arbitrary loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isLinkedToStart(Node head) {
    if (head == null) {
        return false;
    }
    Node probe = head.next;
    while (probe != null) {
        if (probe == head) {
            return true;
        }
        if(probe.seen) {
            return false;
        }

        probe.seen = true;
        probe = probe.next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

can you modify your node structure, or no? That is, can you add something like `node.seen == false` and then toggle that on as you cycle, and then modify this code^ to check to make sure nodes are unseen while looping, and return false if it comes across a "seen" node? (Implemented above)